# How to automatically recompute margin whenever browser width is readjusted

Tags: html, css

So i came up with an example in which i have the following in HTML:

[image]

and the focus will be just at the two sentences i pointed out in the picture above.

So as shown, one has the sentence "This is a short sentence" and the one at the bottom is basically a longer sentence.

Now I set the margin of the short sentence in css in such a way where it aligns with the bottom longer sentence.

So based on this example, what i want to achieve is **basically to allow the browser to recalculate the margin whenever i adjust the width of the browser.**

Right now if i **slightly adjust the width** of the browser, we see that the **sentence is going off track and no longer aligned with the bottom sentence**.

[image]

If the **original aligned state has a margin-left of 45.3%**, how do i **get the equivalent** whenever the **browser width is adjusted**?

Would appreciate some help on this.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#first {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 35%;
    height: 90vh;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/*Margin for sentence set here*/
#sentence1 {
    margin-left: 45.3%;
}

#second {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "avc_label_style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "container">
    <div id = "first">
      <div id = "sentence1">This is a short sentence</div>
      <div id = "sentence2">This is a very long sentence long sentence long sentence long sentence</div>
    </div>
    <div id = "second">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam hendrerit quam et tellus tincidunt posuere. Vivamus malesuada sapien quis elit semper, tristique elementum lectus condimentum. Suspendisse quis accumsan mi. Sed vel eros laoreet, lobortis purus eget, ornare metus. Donec non magna dictum, pretium justo id</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add another div in there, wrapping #sentence1 and #sentence2.
Then make that div as long as it needs to be and right align all contents.

This should work:

```html
<div id = "container">
  <div id = "first">
    <div class=".wrapper">
      <div id = "sentence1">This is a short sentence</div>
      <div id = "sentence2">This is a very long sentence long sentence long sentence long sentence</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id = "second">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```